# Using parse as back end for OS X and Windows app

Tags: windows, macos, parse-platform

Can I host application data (images, short videos, etc.) for both versions of my application (Mac App Store, and Windows app store) on parse.com? The mac app store guidelines are confusing to me; it looks like they are saying that any application data I store in a backend service can not be accessible from another application. I'm not sure if this means that a windows version of my application can't access the same backend data as my mac version?

I tried to ask this question on the mac developer forum but it required me to pay to be part of the mac developer program.

thnx

Brian

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use Parse.com as the backend for both applications. I cannot find where on the Mac App Store review guidelines that it says you can't access data from another application. If you edit your question with the rule it will help.

If you're referring to:

**2.29** *Apps that do not use the appropriate Mac OS X APIs for modifying user data stored by other Apps (e.g bookmarks, Address Book or Calendar entries) will be rejected*

then you're alright. This isn't talking about accessing data from a backend.